# Using @QuerydslPredicate with NOT @Entity class

Tags: spring-boot, querydsl, predicate

I have controller in spring boot like this:

```
@GetMapping("/search")
    public List<PersonResponse> getDataByFilter(@QuerydslPredicate(root = PersonResponse.class) Predicate data) {...}
```

but here `@QuerydslPredicate(root = PersonResponse.class)` `PersonResponse` in not annotated with @Entity, it's simply a dto bean. Is there any way I can use not @Entity class for Predicate?

I also tried to use `package-info.java`:

```
@QueryEntities({
        PersonResponse.class,
})
package com.dto;

import com.querydsl.core.annotations.QueryEntities;
```

This generates `QPersonResponse` class but it extends `BeanPath` insted of `EntityPathBase`, and when I call controller I got Exception:

```
com.dto.QPersonResponse cannot be cast to com.querydsl.core.types.EntityPath
```